# Create LinkedList with JavaScript but logging the instance is not as expected

Tags: javascript, linked-list

I am learning the LinkedList data structure with JavaScript. So here is what I tried with the Chrome snippets

```
(function(){
    function LinkedList() {
        let Node = function(element) {
            this.element = element;
            this.next = null;
        }
    
        let head = null;
    
        this.append = function(element) {
            let node = new Node(element);
            let current;
    
            if (head == null) {
                head = node;
            } else {
                current = head;
                while(current.next){
                    current = current.next;
                }
                current.next = node;
            }
        }
    };

    let l1 = new LinkedList();
    l1.append(3);
    l1.append(4);
    l1.append(2);

    console.log(l1);
})()
```

Basically I created a LinkedList function with the append method, then I created a new instance named l1 and append 3 elements to it. At the end of the code, I am expecting to log the instance l1 which maybe something similar to

```
[
{element: 3, next: 4},
{element: 4, next: 2},
{element: 2, next:null},
]
```

But what I actually got is the LinkedList function rather than the new instance

```
LinkedList {append: ƒ}
append: ƒ (element)
```

So I am not sure what's my misunderstanding in between? and what might be the right way to test a LinkedList in JavaScript? Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JavaScript LinkedList](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66530541/javascript-linkedlist)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can directly loop over the linked list to create an array.

```js
(function(){
    function LinkedList() {
        let Node = function(element) {
            this.element = element;
            this.next = null;
        }
    
        let head = null;
    
        this.append = function(element) {
            let node = new Node(element);
            let current;
    
            if (head == null) {
                head = node;
            } else {
                current = head;
                while(current.next){
                    current = current.next;
                }
                current.next = node;
            }
        },
        this.toArray = function(){
            var arr = [];
            for(var curr = head; curr != null; curr = curr.next) arr.push(curr);
            return arr;
        }
    };

    let l1 = new LinkedList();
    l1.append(3);
    l1.append(4);
    l1.append(2);

    console.log(l1.toArray());
})()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try `console.log(l1.append(1))` But if you want to see all your data neat and clean you need to define a function in your linked list to console.log the data(or element, in your case) of each node